# Evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi\mathrm{i}} \int_{\alpha} \frac{\cos z}{2\sin z-\sqrt2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z:\frac{\pi}4<|z|< \frac{5\pi}4\}$ and let $\alpha$ be a closed curve in $D$ whose winding number about the origin is $2$. Evaluate

$$\frac1{\pi\mathrm{i}} \int_{\alpha}\frac{\cos z}{2\sin z-\sqrt2}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Now the denominator $(2\sin z-\sqrt2)$ has a zero on the real axis in $D$ at $z=\frac{3\pi}4$. I thought since the denominator is not zero on the unit circle I can use the substitution $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ and then the residue theorem but I don't know how to handle it with the given curve which has winding number $2$ about zero.

Comment: If the curve has winding number $2$ about $z=0$, this curve also has winding number $2$ about the pole $z=\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: It depends on whether the curve contains the point $\frac{3\pi}4$ once, twice, or not at all.  (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: Darn, for some reason, I read $D=\left\{z\,\Big|\,\frac{3\pi}{4}<|z|<\frac{5\pi}{4}\right\}$.  Then, the answer, just as in David's comment, depends on $\alpha$.

Comment: @David: So how can I consider these three cases? Thanks.

Comment: As the denominator is also zero at $z=\frac\pi4$ (and at no other relevant points), you need to count the residue there twice, and the residue at $z=\frac{3\pi}4$ once, twice or not at all.  Are you sure the domain wasn't $\frac\pi4<|z|<\frac{3\pi}4$? - that would be a more sensible question.

Comment: @David: Yes the domain is correct. So do we only need to use residue theorem?

Comment: Residue theorem should do it.